# Getting response as 'Unauthorized' while sending access token via URI Query Parameter

Tags: api, rest, oauth-2.0, yii2

We are creating REST API and implemented oAuth 2, using YII framework.

We are facing a strange issue, while we are trying to access the resource and sending access token via "Authorization Request Header Field" we are getting the expected output.
e.g.
curl -i -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXX"

Whereas while we are trying to send the access token via "URI Query Parameter" we are getting response as "Unauthorized".

e.g.

https://server.example.com/resource?access_token=XXXXXX&p=q

Your suggestions would be really helpful for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) (Bearer Token Usage) defines 3 ways to pass an access token to a protected resource endpoint.

1. Via Authorization header. ([2.1. Authorization Request Header Field](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.1))
2. Via a form parameter access_token. ([2.2. Form-Encoded Body Parameter](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.2))
3. Via a query parameter access_token. ([2.3. URI Query Parameter](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.3))

Among the above, only the first way is mandatory. It seems your authorization server does not support the third way.

#### Addition for the comment

Below is an example to support all the 3 ways in PHP. See "[3. Extract Access Token](https://www.authlete.com/documents/definitive_guide/protected_resource#extract)" in "[Protected Resource](https://www.authlete.com/documents/definitive_guide/protected_resource)" for details and for other examples in Ruby and Java.

```php
/**
 * Function to extract an access token from a request.
 */
function extract_access_token()
{
    // The value of Authorization header.
    $header = $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'];
 
    // If the value is in the format of 'Bearer access-token'.
    if ($header != null && preg_match('/^Bearer[ ]+(.+)/i', $header, $captured))
    {
        // Return the value extracted from Authorization header.
        return $captured;
    }
 
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')
    {
        // Return the value of 'access_token' query parameter.
        return $_GET['access_token'];
    }
    else
    {
        // Return the value of 'access_token' form parameter.
        return $_POST['access_token'];
    }
}
```

I don't know Yii, but my guess is that simply the framework does not contain code like the above.

Comment: Takahiko are u talking about that authorization server's operating system doesn't support third way or the php yii application which is running in authorization server doesn't support third way?

Comment: Operating systems do not matter. Instead, it's just a problem in the implementation of the protected resource endpoint. See the addition in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Takahio, your input helped us a lot. Yii2 support "Authorization Request Header Field"  by default, we updated the endpoint to support "URI Query Parameter". File to extend : HttpBearerAuth.php